# Direct product of periodic elements is periodic.

Tags: ring-theory

**Definition:** An element $p$ of a ring $R$ is called periodic if, there exists distinct positive integer $k$ and $l$ such that $p^k=p^l$.

**My Question:** Let $x,y$ be two periodic elements of a ring $R$. Then $(x,y)$ is a periodic element of the ring $S:=R×R$.

My attempt: Let $x,y$ be two periodic elements of a ring $R$. Then, there exist $k\neq l,m\neq n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x^k=x^l$ and $y^m=y^n$. Hence $(x,y)^{km}=(x^{lm},y^{kn})$. Now, what should I do?

Comment: You have to prove that there exist distinct integers $a$ and $b$ such that $(x,y)^a = (x,y)^b$. I think you're well on your way to doing that, but note that you haven't actually done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer of my question which is as follows:

Suppose that $x^k=x^l (k>l)$ and  $y^m=y^n (m>n)$. Then $x^l=x^k=x^{k-l+l}=x^{2(k-l)+l}=\cdots=x^{r(k-l)+l}$ and $y^n=y^m=y^{m-n+n}=y^{2(m-n)+n}=\cdots=y^{r(m-n)+n}$ for any positive integer $r$. Let $s=(k-l)(m-n)$ and $t=max\{l,n\}$. Then $(x,y)^{s+t}=(x,y)^{t}.$